# load text property of label from datatable

Tags: c#

I want load the lsbel lbl agreed amount from a value from database
my code is

```
public void Vehiclenocomboboxload()
       {

           OleDbConnection oleDbConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString);
           oleDbConnection1.Open();

           OleDbCommand oleDbCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT driverassignmastertable.drivername, driverassignmastertable.vehicleno, driverassignmastertable.amount, driverassignmastertable.driverpk FROM driverassignmastertable WHERE(((driverassignmastertable.jobcodepk)= @jobcodepk))", oleDbConnection1);
           oleDbCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobcodepk", cmbjobcode.SelectedValue);
           OleDbDataReader reader = oleDbCommand1.ExecuteReader();
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();


           dt.Columns.Add("vehicleno", typeof(string));
           dt.Columns.Add("drivername", typeof(string));
           dt.Columns.Add("amount", typeof(int));
           dt.Columns.Add("driverpk", typeof(int));
           dt.Load(reader);
           if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("No vehicle Assigned to this Jobcode");

               cmbVehicleno.DataSource = null;
               txtvehicleno.Text = "";
           }
           else
           {

               cmbVehicleno.ValueMember = "driverpk";
               cmbVehicleno.DisplayMember = "vehicleno";
               lblagreeamount.Text = "amount"

               cmbVehicleno.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;



           }

           oleDbConnection1.Close();

       }
```

all is fine but my problem is my lblagreed amount is not getting any value from database 
my code part was
 lblagreeamount.Text = "amount"

can anyone suggest any other databinding method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this

```
lblagreeamount.Text = dt.Row[0]["amount"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned a value to your label, just the static "amount":

```
lblagreeamount.Text = "amount"
```

You need to read the appropriate field of the `DataTable`'s first row:

```
lblagreeamount.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("amount").ToString();
```

Comment: thank you sir but i feel above easy and this didnt work  may be my mistake